# Angular in strict mode with ngrx

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store

I am trying learn ngrx, but I can't seem to find any working examples of it with angular strict mode. Is it compatible with strict mode? I have tried several different implementations I've found none of which were made with strict mode in mind and have not been able to get any of them to work. I disable strict mode I can get the example from https://ngrx.io/guide/store/walkthrough , but I can not get it to work with strict mode.

It has an issue with createSelector with readonly arrays.

**book.model.ts**

```
export interface Book {
    id: string;
    volumeInfo: {
      title: string;
      authors: Array<string>;
    };
}
```

**app.state.ts:**

```
import { Book } from '../model/book.model';

export interface AppState {
  books: ReadonlyArray<Book>;
  collection: ReadonlyArray<string>;
}
```

**book.selector.ts**

```
import { createSelector, createFeatureSelector } from "@ngrx/store";
import { AppState } from "./app.state";
import { Book } from "../model/book.model";
 
export const selectBooks = createSelector(
  (state: AppState) => state.books,
  (books: Array<Book>) => books
);
 
export const selectCollectionState = createFeatureSelector<
  AppState,
  ReadonlyArray<string>
>("collection");
 
export const selectBookCollection = createSelector(
  selectBooks,
  selectCollectionState,
  (books: Array<Book>, collection: Array<string>) => {
    return collection.map((id) => books.find((book) => book.id === id));
  }
);
```

**books.actions.ts**

```
import { createAction, props } from '@ngrx/store';

//bookId: type is unknown perhaps number?

export const addBook = createAction(
    '[Book List] Add Book',
    props<{ bookId:any }>()
  );
   
  export const removeBook = createAction(
    '[Book Collection] Remove Book',
    props<{ bookId:any }>()
  );
   
  export const retrievedBookList = createAction(
    '[Book List/API] Retrieve Books Success',
    props<{ Book:any }>()
  );
```

**books.reducer.ts**

```
import { createReducer, on, Action } from '@ngrx/store';

import { retrievedBookList } from './books.actions';
import { Book } from '../model/book.model';

export const initialState: ReadonlyArray<Book> = [];

export const booksReducer = createReducer(
  initialState,
  on(retrievedBookList, (state, { Book }) => [...Book])
);
```

**collection.reducer.ts**

```
import { createReducer, on, Action } from '@ngrx/store';
import { addBook, removeBook } from './books.actions';
 
export const initialState: ReadonlyArray<string> = [];
 
export const collectionReducer = createReducer(
  initialState,
  on(removeBook, (state, { bookId }) => state.filter((id) => id !== bookId)),
  on(addBook, (state, { bookId }) => {
    if (state.indexOf(bookId) > -1) return state;
 
    return [...state, bookId];
  })
);
```

Comment: I cannot check your code at the moment, but afaik ReadonlyArray is a different type than array (unlike in e.g. Java, at least in some cases).

So

      on(retrievedBookList, (state, { Book }) => [...Book])

returns a **non** readonly array through the spreading syntax but you expect a ReadonlyArray thru your state definition as defined above.

Another idea might be that serialization thru actions actually breaks the conecpt of strict mode, but I'd have to check that.

What exactly is the error message you are getting?

Comment: I run `@ngrx` in strict mode so it's definitely possible if that's your question.

Answer (score 1):

The walkthrough needs a few changes to work with strict mode. As you've said, the ReadonlyArray is a problem, so update the Application state as follows:

**app.state.ts**

```js
export interface AppState {
  books: Book[];
  collection: string[];
}
```

However, to get it working, you also to make changes elsewhere.

**books.selectors.ts**

```js
export const selectBooks = createSelector(
  (state: AppState) => state.books,
  (books: Array<Book>) => books
);

export const selectCollectionState = createFeatureSelector<AppState, string[]>(
  'collection'
);

export const selectBookCollection = createSelector(
  selectBooks,
  selectCollectionState,
  (books: Array<Book>, collection: Array<string>) => {
    {
      let collect: (Book | undefined)[] = collection.map((id) =>
        books.find((book) => book.id === id)
      );
      let result = collect.filter<Book>(isNotNullOrUndefined);
      return result;
    }
  }
);

export function isNotNullOrUndefined<T>(
  input: null | undefined | T
): input is T {
  return input != null;
}
```

The selectors need to change because the type `Book | undefined` is not the same as the type `Book` in strict mode. Therefore, you need to use solutions as outlined in the comments here:
https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16069.

That's where I found the `isNotNullOrUndefined` function.